# Algoritmo de Divisão e Conquista

Tags: java, array, recursão

Estou tendo problemas em fazer um algoritmo de divisão e conquista da soma dos elementos de um arranjo.

```
public static int somatorio(int[] a, int numElem) {
    if(numElem == 0) {
       return 0;
    }else if(numElem == 1){
       return a[0];
    }

    int meio = numElem/2;
    int dTamanho = numElem - meio; //tamanho lado direito
    int eSoma = somatorio(a, meio); //soma lado esquerdo
    int dSoma = somatorio(a, dTamanho); //soma lado direito

    return eSoma + dSoma;
}
```

Não estou conseguindo realizar essa soma recursivamente, como posso arrumar meu código?

Comment: Primeiro: isto não tem divisão e conquista algum, tem divisão, complicação e faz o mesmo que não dividido. Segundo: porque não faz iterativo que muito mais fácil, e sem divisão?

Comment: Trabalho de faculdade ahhahah. Estou com dificuldade nessa parte....teria então alguma dica de como melhorar esse código ou onde posso buscar informações?

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE:** *consegui resolver meu problema, caso alguém também esteja na dúvida deixarei o meu código*

```
public static int somatorio(int[] a, int inicio. int fim) {
     if(inicio == fim) {
        return a[inicio];
     }else
        if(inicio == fim-1) {
           return a[inicio] + a[fim];
        }else {
           int meio = (fim + inicio)/2;
           int eSoma = somatorio(a, inicio, meio); //soma lado esquerdo
           int dSoma = somatorio(a, meio+1, fim); //soma lado direito

           return eSoma + dSoma;
        }
}
```